# How do I find the particular solution for $ y''' + y'' + y' + y = \cos t + e^{-t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving it as $A\cos t + B\sin t + Ce^{-t}$ but I got $0$ in the end after I differentiate and substitute into the equation.

Comment: Take $Cte^-{t}$, then you will be able to solve it. That extra $t$ will do the trick. Same for the other two terms

Comment: Here is the [MathJax Handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Try $t\cos(t)$ and similarly $t\sin(t),te^{-t}$.

Comment: put firstly Z=y'+y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from complementary solution, we find the solution contains $e^{-t}$, $\cos t$, and $\sin t$

so the particular solution should be
$$y_p=tA\cos t+tB\sin t+Cte^{-t}$$